# make 2 layers div position over each other without overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have 2 layers div(div7 & lildiv7) I want to make it looks like 1 layer, the top layer is partially transparent, so we can see the background picture underneath it.
My problem is, the top layer's border displays slightly smaller than the bottom one. How can I make these two divs match at the exact position with each other?

```css
div {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 20px 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div7 {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url("gradients.jpg");
}

.lildiv7 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(238, 174, 202);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238, 174, 202, 1) 9%, rgba(170, 163, 203, 1) 44%, rgba(167, 190, 200, 0.010723039215686292) 74%, rgba(122, 153, 190, 0.137) 100%);
  padding: 20px 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: translate(0px, -29.5px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="div7">
    <div class="lildiv7">transparency</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `div` padding and margin rules will apply to the `<div class="div7">` element as well. Try moving them to a specific CSS class instead.

Comment: I've changed the `div` padding to 29px for top and bottom, and looks like it works now. thanks